# From these functions, how to determine which grows faster without graphing?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

How are you intuitively able to tell the Big-Oh of the functions and what order they are on?
$$f(n)=3^n$$
$$g(n)=5^{3log_3{n}}$$
Note this is $5$ raised to $3log_3n$
$$h(n)=1024^{log_2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the idea is to look at things that may even appear to be gigantic but that may end up getting swamped as *n* grows.

As an example, consider which of $f(n) = 3^n$ and $g(n) = 1024^{\log_2 n}$ may grow faster.  1024 seems a lot larger than 3, but the 3’s pile up at the rate of an entire tripling with each unit increment of $n$. By contrast, those admittedly sizable 1024’s are only showing up at the rate of $\log_2 n$, so for instance, once the 1024 corresponding to $n = 256$ makes its appearance, we don’t see the next 1024 until $n = 512$, and during $g$’s wait for it, $f$ will have grown by a factor of $3^{256}$. And things only gets worse for $g$ because the wait time for each new 1024 will **double** forever. So although 3 may be dwarfed by 1024, once $n$ gets warmed up, the 3’s easily win because there are just so many more of them than there are of the ever-rarer 1024’s.

And of course, that intuition is backed up by the algebra:

> $1024^{\log_2 n} = 2^{10\log_2 n} = n^{10}$,

and $(n+1)^{10}$ exceeds $n^{10}$ by only something along the lines of $10 n^9$, whereas $3^{n+1}$ is a full three times as large as $3^n$.

Answer (score 0):

The exponential of a logarithm is a power ($a^{b\log_c n}=e^{b\log a\log n/\log c}=n^{b\log a/\log c}$), so the exponential "wins".

To decide between the last two, you cannot spare the comparison of the exponents.

> $$5^{3/\log 3}=125^{1/\log3}<1024^{1/\log 2}.$$